# Is there a profitable way to record user actions in textarea?

Tags: javascript, jquery-plugins, macros, textarea, jquery-events

I need to send bunch of commands to the server on timer - like:

```
put(0,"hello")
del(4,1)
put(4," is around the corner")
```

so I need to monitor and record all of the user input and compile/flush it on the timeout (idle), something like macros.

I can record all things happening `onKeyUp`/`onKeyDown`/`onMouseDown`/`onMouseUp` using textarea cursor position and keys information (and make it cross-browser *some time* later) but I can't handle things like pasting using mouse right button and selecting 'Paste' or pasting from the menu (I can handle `onChange`, but I will have no information is it pasted or already recorded as pressed keys and it fires only after focus change). Even pasting from context menu fires some useful info, but the menu from the browser is the only thing, giving nothing for Javascript.

Is there any plugin for jQuery or something like that and do I really have no other ways to implement it without comparing current-document and document-a-second-before?

**Upd.:** There are events for handling `cut`/`copy`/`paste`: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html , but what about 
the `undo` one?

P.S. I will show a macro-recording code when I'll finish, if someone really needs it. And to finish it properly, I just need the `undo` handling possibility. Current version is here: http://code.google.com/p/sametimed/source/browse/WebContent/module-editor.js, look for `compileCommands` method.

Comment: I've written "Pasting from menu fires nothing", but it is not correct, 'paste' event is fired in most of browsers as [stefpet](http://stackoverflow.com/users/25815/stefpet) mentioned.

Comment: disabling right mouse buttons and override the Ctrl C, V, X, Z are not preferrable?

Comment: No, that's no good - I'm writing an editor with javascript, it must give all possible functionality to user, but also communicate with server (*makes a mark to himself*: find out how other js-editors behave theirselves). Anyway, I do not know a possible way to disable browser 'Edit' menu.

Comment: If there is a way to disable Undo command from menu, I'll use it and make a special button for it - if there is nothing else to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are events for cut/copy/paste you may listen to, depending on browser. So if they are triggered you may use them, otherwise fall back to more tedious work-around.

See: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/cutcopypaste.html

Comment: seems I've forgot about these events and may be they'll really help me - thank you.

Comment: ok, and do the handler for `undo` exists (from browser menu or context menu)? I've found everything I've needed, but not this :(.